# Libraries for .net which can accept queries from javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm having some difficulty expressing myself clearly, allow me to use an example. (Yes this would be very dangerous to do)

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/customer/query",
  data: { sql: "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER" }
});
```

Server side:

```
public JSonResult query(string sql)
{
  var dataset = MySqlConnection.Execute(sql);

  return ConvertDataSetToJson(dataset);
}
```

While this is obviously a very simple (and dangerous!) example, I think it illustrates what I am looking for; some sort of library with a standardized querying language for .net which can parse queries from javascript.

I would obviously not want to use SQL directly like in the example.

Comment: Sounds like [OData](http://www.odata.org/) could be what you want.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question. Your client side having an intimate knowledge of your data layer can't be as good idea.

Comment: @gene looks promising, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OData](http://www.odata.org/) allows you to provide a data source via HTTP. Visual Studio comes with a project template for OData called [WCF Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx). OData allows to secure access to the data source (for all CRUD operations).

There are some [major sites](http://www.odata.org/ecosystem#liveservices) providing OData services, for example [StackExchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or [eBay](http://ebayodata.cloudapp.net/). Example to query the StackOverflow OData service: [Users on SO named Jon Skeet](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/Users?$filter=DisplayName%20eq%20%27Jon%20Skeet%27).

According to the [OData website](http://www.odata.org/blog/2011/2/9/new-javascript-library-for-odata-and-beyond), JavaScript is supported as a client language.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON-RPC for this, here is [JSON-RPC for C#](http://jayrock.berlios.de/). You can read more about [JSON-RPC on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC).

Comment: Looks to me like this is just another way of specifying which methods to call on the server side? I would still need to implement "GetCustomerById", "GetCustomerByName", "GetCustomerByDepartment" and so on.. I want to avoid doing specific methods like that on the server and just parse queries directly from javascript

Comment: @Toodleey there is no reason why not to create method `query` using JSON-RPC

Comment: I think I am having trouble explaining what I am looking for. I want to write my "SQL" in javascript and then have the server parse it and execute it. But I cannot use sql because that would be a major security issue.